# Add title to woocommerce/ wordpress tags

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce

I'm trying to add titles to my wordpress tags, mainly the woocommerce ones. I can't find anything on this as every search I try brings up 'title tags'.

I guess jQuery could do it, but would it be better to use PHP?

Comment: *"I'm trying to add titles"*, please share your attempts and check the guide [ask].

Comment: Yes sorry. I've managed to do it with jQuery as below...it works so I am going with it, but if anyone has any better suggestions I am all ears! `<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".tagged_as a" ).each(function( index ) {
        var tst = jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery( this ).addClass( tst );
  jQuery( this ).attr( 'title', tst );
  //jQuery( this ).addClass( "normalTip" );
    });
 jQuery("p:has(img)").addClass('p-image');
});


</script>`

Comment: Actually for some reason this does not work on my remote site! There are no errors showing up on console either. Is there some php I should be using here as a preference anyway?